# Adding Separators To a ListView

Tags: android

I have a listView which gets its data from a JsonArray objects. It gets names of people from a DB. The query sorts the names alphabetically. I want to add headers to the ListView, which shows the starting alphabet followed by the names of the people. I tried using if-else inside the try block but gives problems while scrolling the list, can anyone suggest me a good solution for this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the best options is to use [StickyListHeaders](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders).